# Javascript TextArea Control To Last Line Automatically When Page Refreshes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm Coding A JavaScript For My Web Page You Can Check It Out [Here](http://jntunews.com/simulators/4/omu.php). This Page is used to execute all commands.. For Example There is a command "ZDYE:SET,0&&98:ACT=ENA;" When You Type This In The Command Prompt. It Executes The Code. I'm Having a Small Error. Enter The Code and Hit Enter The Page Refreshes And Executes The Code. But The Cursor Position is Moving To First Line. After Entering a Set Of Commands We To Scroll Down To See The Code. But I Want To Scroll Down Automatically To Last line After Executing The Code.. For Example Type The Code "ZDYE:SET,0&&98:ACT=ENA;" and Hit Enter. Do It Repeatedly Till the Scroll Bar Comes. You Will Understand My Problem.

To Get The Cursor Position To Last Line I Used This Code.

```
// JavaScript

function moveCaretToEnd(el) {
    if (typeof el.selectionStart == "number") {
        el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = el.value.length;
    } else if (typeof el.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        el.focus();
        var range = el.createTextRange();
        range.collapse(false);
        range.select();
    }
}

var textarea = document.getElementById("text");
    textarea.onfocus = function() {
    moveCaretToEnd(this);

    // Work around Chrome's little problem
    textarea.onmouseup = function() {
        // Prevent further mouseup intervention
        moveCaretToEnd(this);
        textarea.onmouseup = null;
        return false;
    };
};
```

But There is No use Again The Cursor Position Is Going To First Line. Please Help Me

Comment: Maybe you are updating the cursor location after textarea's content changing?

Comment: No. I'm updating Text Area Cursor Location in <head> Part of HTML Code